# Child div exceeds parent div when responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Does anyone have any pointers on this? I have this issue a lot with responsive (this one is for an email specifically).

Example of the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/53rQ8.jpg

My child element exceeds the parent only when resizing for mobile (this window is sized at 375px).

This usually only happens when I have added a margin/padding which expands the right scroll the same distance. So for example here I have a 30px padding on the left and right sides so there is 60 extra pixels on right (scrolling to the right this is what you see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCOGY.jpg )

Looking for a fix that will work in the future and not just for this design but here is the code I'm working with currently:

```
<table class="row" style="height:100%;width:100%; max-width:inherit">
  <tr>
      <th class="small-12" style="padding-left:30px;padding-right:30px; padding bottom:15px; padding-top:10px; margin-right:-100pximportant;;left:0;right:0; max-width:inherit">
     <h1 style="color:#e41e26; font-size:1.35rem; font-weight:500">Visit NRTC at Booth #363 at TechAdvantage 2018</h1>
     <p style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; font-size:1.1rem; line-height:1.8em;">See what our Demand Management partners<strong>&mdash;Nest, Aquanta,</strong> and <strong>DVI</strong>&mdash;can do for you</p>
      </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `box-sizing: border-box;` to include an element's padding and border into the width, which is especially useful when you use a percentage value like `100%` for `width`. Otherwise (in this case) the width will become more than 100%, which will overflow.